# How to add new git repository file thru git patch

Tags: git, git-patch

There are two Repositories : project-version-1 and project-version-2.

1. project-version-1 dir has files : calculator/src/add.c calculator/src/subtract.c calculator/src/multiply.c and it does not have support for some feature (say division operation)
2. project-version-2 has the fix. But the fix is on new file say calculator/src/division.c

## Problem :

I have to provide the patch(fix) to project-version-1 from the project-version-2 git repository. The patch should be a single diff file. we can't ask the customer do "git add new-file" etc. how do i generate a patch for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the new file in your `project-version-1` and you need to add the file by using the following commands:

```sh
git add -N division.c
```

This allows you to add an untracked file as your file is new.

And then add the modifications interactively by using

```sh
git add -p
```

You will then obtain a console with the following message

```sh
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?
```

And then you may edit to see  or directly stage the whole new file as it a new file.
`y` is for accepting to stage and `e` for edit

Then to check your changes, you may

```sh
git diff --cached
```

And if you are happy with your changes, you may then export it to a patch file by

```sh
git diff --cached > patch1.patch
```

Comment: Where do i have to add this new file and create a patch ? is it on project-version-1 or project-version-2 ?

Comment: you add it on verson 1 as it i the project which does not have the new file

Comment: Yes it works. Could you please update the answer with where to do this. It would be good for future references. Thank you so much.